# Can Google Cloud functions share a datastore with Appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I have an old AppEngine Java application using the AppEngine datastore. Is this what the marketing renamers at Google now (2019) call "Cloud Datastore"?

Can I create Google Cloud Functions that interact with the same datastore, and what are the steps needed to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the same datastore. Also called/soon-to-be `Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode` (which all older apps will be converted to at some point).

Yes, you can access it from anywhere, even from outside Google Cloud. From [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating#datastore) (emphasis mine):

> You can access [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs) from anywhere using the Cloud
>   Datastore API. Use the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries) to store and
>   retrieve data from Cloud Datastore.
>
> **The same Cloud Datastore data is available regardless of if you use the App Engine libraries, the Google Cloud client libraries, or call
>   the API directly.**

The major steps to access the datastore from a Cloud Function:

- you can't use the GAE-specific client libraries like the one you likely used in your old app, you'll have to use one of the generic [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) (or the [REST](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/) or [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/) APIs)
- you'll have to give your [CF's Identity/service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity) the proper access permissions, see [Setting up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) and [Accessing your database from another platform](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#other-platforms).

Comment: "cloud firestore in datastore mode" lol. You can't make this stuff up!
Much thx